# Exclude related objects before Count

Tags: django, django-orm

For example I've got 3 models `User`, `A`, `B`.

```
class A(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='A_set'
    )


class B(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='B_set'
    )
    a_model = models.ForeignKey(
        'a.A', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='B_set'
    )
```

I would like to get count of `B` where `user` isn't a `creator` of a_model object.

I've tried query:

```
`User.objects.prefetch_related('B_set').last().B_set.exclude(a_model__creator=F('user')).count()`
```

Here is my try with annotation:

```
User.objects.annotate(b_count=Count('B_set', filter=(~Q(B_set__A__creator=F('user')))))
```

But I am getting an error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field.

And then it suggest me fields that relate to User. Also I tried to change `user` to `B_set__user` with `F()` but it didn't help.

Comment: This should be `F('id')`, since this is already the `User` object you are annotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your annotation:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    b_count=Count('B_set', filter=(~Q(B_set__A__creator=F('user'))))
)
```

your `F(..)` attribute refers to a *hypothetical* `User.user` field, but a `User` has (probably) no `user` field.

If you want to refer to the "self" here, you can use `F('pk')` (or `F('id')`, given if `id` is the primary key), so you can write this expression as:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    b_count=Count('B_set', filter=~Q(B_set__a__model__creator=F('pk')))
)
```

This then results in a query like:

```
SELECT user.*,
       COUNT(
           CASE WHEN NOT a.creator_id = user.id AND a.creator_id IS NOT NULL
           THEN b.id ELSE NULL END
       ) AS b_count
FROM user
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON user.id = b.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON b.a_model_id=a.id
GROUP BY user.id
```